# Windows 10 Disk Cleanup keeps showing large amount of Temporary Files

Tags: windows, temporary-files, disk-cleanup

My Windows 10 machine recently started taking a long time to sign in.  Boot, post and getting to the login screen are all fast, but after signing in it takes up to two minutes to reach the desktop.  With all the Windows machines I've built and used over the years that's a long time.

I read that temporary files can affect this.  I started by running Disk Cleanup.  Initially it showed 55.4 GB of Temporary Files.

[image]

After running it now shows 55.2 GB.

[image]

Why would it only remove 0.2 GB?

Using File Explorer I found that %localappdata\temp% has 57GB of files.  Would I be better off just deleting its contents manually?  I'm concerned about the unintended consequences, whatever they could be.

Is there a different utility I should use that will actually delete all the temporary files it finds?

Comment: Yes, you may delete all the files in `%localappdata%\Temp`, but Skip files you can't delete. How much is left?

Comment: Try running Disk Cleanup (cleanmgr) as Administrator and see if that helps

Comment: Did you reboot after cleanup? Some files are locked when in use and cannot be removed until after reboot. Also, try a third-party cleanup tool such as Wise Disk Cleaner -- but read reviews and check at VirusTotal before installing. the tool. Finally, clean WinSxS folder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried running Disk Cleanup as administrator and got the same result.  I also tried rebooting after running Disk Cleanup and found that the 55.2 GB of temp files still remained.  I'm putting the rest in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I manually deleted everything from %localappdata\temp%, emptied the Recycle Bin, then rebooted.  The login was very fast, basically immediate.  Disk Cleanup now shows only 2GB of files.  I'm satisfied that this was a solution because both the posting to windows login page and transition from login to desktop are now very fast like I'm accustomed too.

I plan to create a powershell script to run as a scheduled task that will keep the recycle bin and %localappdata\temp% mostly empty on a regular basis.